# How would you set 2 "child Of" constraints on the same object?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation

How would you set 2 "child Of" constraints on the same object.

I already have a "child Of" constraint on the Hat using the robot hand as target. Because the hat is not parented to the body, it stays stationary when the robot spins 180 degrees on the Z-axis. The hat has a design on one side but because it does not spin with the robot, we cant see the design after the robot has spun around to face the viewer.

My question is is it possible to add a 2nd "child Of" constraint on the Hat and use the robot body as target? How can this be set up?[image]

Comment: Can become really messy if you use more then one "child of" constraint, you would need to weight each constraint and adjust them depending on the situation. I would suggest to look at an Add-on called ["Dynamic Parent"](https://blender-addons.org/dynamic-parent-addon/)

Comment: I will check it out, but I still would like to be able to do the animation using a standard method without a add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for an answer, and I've actually found a workaround myself.
Create a new armature for the hat, scale the root bone and make it small, then parent the hat to your new armature. You will have 2 armature sets and you can use "Child Of" again. If you changed the influence slider, you may have not the desired influence movements, so what worked for me was to subtract the first armature influence with the new one.